# Bazel running a nodejs target and expressing dependencies

Tags: node.js, bazel

I am building a simple nodejs application and would like to get it to run using Bazel (newbie in bazel) - Using bazel version 0.28.1

[image]

## My package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodeapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "4.17.15"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

## My index.js

```
const _ = require("lodash")
const ver = _.VERSION
console.log(ver);
```

## My BUILD.bazel

```
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "nodejs_binary")

nodejs_binary(
  name = "app",
  install_source_map_support = False,
  data = [
    "index.js",
    "@npm//lodash",
  ],
  entry_point = "index.js",
)
```

## My WORKSPACE

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_NODEJS_VERSION = "0.32.2"
RULES_NODEJS_SHA256 = 
"6d4edbf28ff6720aedf5f97f9b9a7679401bf7fca9d14a0fff80f644a99992b4"
http_archive(
  name = "build_bazel_rules_nodejs",
  sha256 = RULES_NODEJS_SHA256,
  url =`"https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/releases/download/%s/rules_nodejs-%s.tar.gz" % (RULES_NODEJS_VERSION, RULES_NODEJS_VERSION),`
)


load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "node_repositories", "npm_install")

# Setup the Node.js toolchain & install our npm dependencies into @npm
npm_install(
  name = "npm",
  package_json = "//:package.json",
  package_lock_json = "//:package-lock.json",
)
```

From the node_app directory, I execute `bazel clean && bazel run //:app` and it works fine

[image]

Now questions that I have are

1. Any way to get the nodejs_binary to spread all of node_modules as opposed to going in and listing them as "@npm//lodash" in the BUILD.bazel file (like using a filegroup perhaps)
2. If I delete the node_modules directory, the bazel execution stops working after that. It feels like it did not see the need to do "npm install" again. What am I missing?
3. If I do not change the package.json but add more code to index.js, are subsequent builds intelligent enough to not do "npm install" since it is not required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any way to get the nodejs_binary to spread all of node_modules as opposed to going in and listing them as "@npm//lodash" in the BUILD.bazel file (like using a filegroup perhaps)

This behaviour was deprecated in version 0.13.0 of rules_nodejs, the recommended approach
is to use fine grained npm dependencies which are setup with the `yarn_install` or `npm_install` rules. This helps with reducing the time required to setup runfiles for targets. The full example and explanation is in the docs for the `node_modules` attribute in the `nodejs_binary` builtin rule here: https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/Built-ins.html

> If I do not change the package.json but add more code to index.js, are subsequent builds intelligent enough to not do "npm install" since it is not required?

Yes, bazel shouldn't run another `npm install` or rebuild the `node_module` directory for a source change like that. Infact, running `bazel run` with only changing a line in a js file should be near instant.